# Prove that $E_0$ is transcendental

Tags: prime-numbers, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

Consider the non-negative natural numbers:

$0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19\dots$

Encode the primes as $1$, the rest as $0$.

$E = 0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1\dots$

The number $E_0$ is

$001.10101000101000101\dots$ (i.e. the binary pattern of the primes)

$E_0$ is irrational in every base due to a *[simple proof](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0954)* which shows that the binary pattern of the primes, $E$, is not periodic.

Since the location of the (binary) point is arbitrary, if we locate the point one place to the right, we obtain $E_1 (=0011.0101\dots)$.

So $\dfrac{E_1}{E_0}$ is the integer $2$.

Since $E_0$ is irrational in every number base, we are led to the interesting aphorism:

"Every integer greater than one is the ratio of two irrational numbers. Each of these irrational numbers expresses the infinite pattern of the prime numbers".

Now, prove that $E_0$ is transcendental.

Note that $C_0 = 110.01010111010111010\dots$ (i.e. the binary pattern of the composites)

and $E_0+C_0 = 111.11111111111111111\dots$

All contributions acknowledged.